# Objective-C code for AirPrint

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, printing

How can make a IBAction method for printing a UITextView with AirPrint in objective-c?

Answer (score 24):

Check whether printing is available:

```
if ([UIPrintInteractionController isPrintingAvailable])
{
    // Available
} else {
    // Not Available
}
```

Print after button click:

```
-(IBAction) buttonClicked: (id) sender;
{
    NSMutableString *printBody = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",self.encoded.text, self.decoded.text];
    [printBody appendFormat:@"\n\n\n\nPrinted From *myapp*"];

     UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
     pic.delegate = self;

     UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
     printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
     printInfo.jobName = self.titleLabel.text;
     pic.printInfo = printInfo;

     UISimpleTextPrintFormatter *textFormatter = [[UISimpleTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithText:printBody];
     textFormatter.startPage = 0;
     textFormatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0); // 1 inch margins
     textFormatter.maximumContentWidth = 6 * 72.0;
     pic.printFormatter = textFormatter;
     [textFormatter release];
     pic.showsPageRange = YES;

     void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
     ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
     if (!completed && error) {
     NSLog(@"Printing could not complete because of error: %@", error);
     }
     };

    [pic presentFromBarButtonItem:self.rightButton animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

}
```

Originally posted by '87vert' at [iPhone Dev SDK](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/): [Airprint Tutorial - Simple Print File](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/67176-airprint-tutorial-simple-print-file-30-lines-code.html)

Comment: It works fine, make sure you implemented it correctly. Check the post by 'twerner' at iPhone Dev SDK for another example (link to specific thread provided in answer).

Comment: That was great.  I wasn't planning on implementing AirPrinting in my app but I just tried it from this tutorial and I finished in like 10 minutes.  Thats awesome.  Thanks.

Comment: what the hell is "encoded.text" and "decoded.text" ?!

Comment: This is silly - it just prints the unformatted text string, from the UITextView. At least, you can print it as a rendered bitmap (more easily) .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479985

Comment: If needed, you will need to add UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate to the header to receive messages from the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

The following method  uses the name of the file to be printed and also the bar button code from where you want the airprint popup to be shown.
It works for me and im  sure will be helpfull

```
-(void)printJob:(int)jobType:(NSString*)jobName:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButton{

NSString *path;
if ([jobName isEqualToString:@"Printout.png"]) {
    path= [self documentsPathForFileName:@"Printout.png"];
}

NSData *mydata=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
pic.delegate = self;
UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
printInfo.jobName = [path lastPathComponent];
printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
pic.printInfo = printInfo;
pic.showsPageRange = YES;
pic.printingItem = mydata;
void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
    if (!completed && error) {
        NSLog(@"Printing could not complete because of error: %@", error);
    }
};

[pic presentFromBarButtonItem:barButton animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

}
```