# Memory management in Airprint(ios)

Tags: objective-c, ios

Here is my situation: I have many bitmap images (high resolution). I want to print these images using Airprint. I have found a way to print images.

```
NSArray array = {image1, image2, image3, image4..... image100}
UIPrintInteractionController *pic;
pic.printingItems = array;
```

So, I know it is possible.

**BUT!! This approach uses a lot of memory. Since I want to print many images and the size of the array grows larger, I can't use this approach. So, I want to know how to print many images in Airprint.**

Is there callback function like this?

```
Airprint says : "give me a next printing image" and then i can give an image.
```

Comment: Check this answer I have posted in [link][1].It may help you
.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690931/objective-c-code-for-airprint/12052720#12052720

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own image class, maybe? With Objective C you don't necessarily need to start with the base UIImage. You could make something that behaves like a UIImage but handles memory better.

Comment: i'm really sorry. i don't understand exactly

Comment: I'm saying, make your own class that implements the same functionality as UIImage, with the same method names. (e.g. it implements -imageOrientation and -size and -scale) Make it use memory more efficiently. Then fill your NSArray with objects of your own class instead of UIImages.

Comment: thanks, but if i have many images that i print , i think this approach(your suggestion) still needs a lot of memory. is there other approach?? :'-(

Comment: Obviously your class would need to manage memory intelligently and not actually load all the images up front.