# Function that sends an image to AirPrint

Tags: objective-c, ios, airprint

Im trying to find a function that lets me print using AirPrint.

I have a button `btnPrint`, that when pressed, should print myPic.jpg to the default AirPrint device. But I cannot figure out if there even is such a function.

I cannot find a lot of documentation on AirPrint in xcode.

Comment: This question is not related to Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple has [documentation on printing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html) that would probably benefit you.

And the following is from [Objective-C code for AirPrint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690931/objective-c-code-for-airprint):

Check wether printing is available:

```
if ([UIPrintInteractionController isPrintingAvailable])
{
    // Available
} else {
    // Not Available
}
```

Print after button click:

```
-(IBAction) buttonClicked: (id) sender;
{
    NSMutableString *printBody = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",self.encoded.text, self.decoded.text];
    [printBody appendFormat:@"\n\n\n\nPrinted From *myapp*"];

     UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
     pic.delegate = self;

     UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
     printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
     printInfo.jobName = self.titleLabel.text;
     pic.printInfo = printInfo;

     UISimpleTextPrintFormatter *textFormatter = [[UISimpleTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithText:printBody];
     textFormatter.startPage = 0;
     textFormatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0); // 1 inch margins
     textFormatter.maximumContentWidth = 6 * 72.0;
     pic.printFormatter = textFormatter;
     [textFormatter release];
     pic.showsPageRange = YES;

     void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
     ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
         if (!completed && error) {
             NSLog(@"Printing could not complete because of error: %@", error);
         }
     };

    [pic presentFromBarButtonItem:self.rightButton animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

}
```

Comment: Hi , I am implementing the same. But i want to know is there any way to know that the printing has been finished ? Is there any delegate method ?